# How non-Google Web Font can be applied to recurly.js hosted fields?

Tags: fonts, webfonts, recurly

I would like to apply a self-hosted commercial font for recurly.js hosted fields. Is there any way to do this?
(The [related documentation of recurly.js](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/getting-started-1#section-fonts) mentions the Google Web Fonts only so I suspect there is no way to achieve this currently)